# How can I write insert command correctly in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write some SQL code. I have a table and I want to add values to that table `Tasks`, but I am getting an error

> Invalid Column Name "Manager"

over `Task_Name`. I identified `Id` as auto-incrementing with  `IDENTITY(1,1)` and I have a `BIT` type value as default 0.

How should I write the expression of insert into?

Here is the code for creating:

```
CREATE TABLE Tasks
(
    ID INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Task_Name VARCHAR(100),
    Situation BIT DEFAULT 0
);
```

Here is the code for `Insert Into`:

```
INSERT INTO (ID, Task_Name, Situation) 
VALUES (1, "Manager");
```

Comment: You provided just 2 values for 3 columns.

Comment: I tried everything.In the beginning I got Situation as "Default 0".So I wrote Null for that firstly.What am I doing wrong?@ rkosegi

Comment: As you mentioned you have an identity column (id) which you mustn't include in your fields during insertion. Or you must let your table with IDENTITY_INSERT to accept manipulating identity columns. Also as  rkosegi said, your fields and values must be equal in number.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO Tasks (Task_Name) values ('Manager')
```

- Don’t specify ID unless turning [identity_insert on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql) (column is marked as `identity` column)
- Don’t include column names to insert default values
- Use `'` to quote strings

Comment: Thank you for your answer.It is solved.@user2864740

Answer (score 0):

```
   INSERT INTO Tasks (Task_Name, Situation) VALUES ('Task_NameValue', 1);
```